# BJT type Gilbert cell does not work

Tags: analog, bjt, npn, multiplier, gilbert-cell

I designed a Gilbert cell for analog multiplication, all the transistors (NPN) are in active region as I checked one by one, however, the result does not seem correct at all. How can I make it better?

[image: the result]

[image: the circuit]

In the first picture, red trace and green trace are supposed to be multiplied, but the blue trace which is the multiplication of these two seems to be out of phase. I mean when red signal is highest, I would expect blue trace to make a peak as well. I do not know what is going on. The NPN I use is simple, generic NPN with DC current gain of approximately 100.

The tutorial that I followed building the circuit is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nmmb0pqTU0&ab_channel=w2aew

[image: second trial with higher frequencies]

I think I have to keep frequencies high so that output and inputs are in phase when multiplied. Now oscillator frequency is of 10 MHz and the lower input voltage has 100 kHz.

Comment: are you sure this isn't a visual artefact? Does the signal still look weird if you zoom in?

Comment: @Hearth I think it does the job of multiplication as I further inspected, but I think there is a phase shift between 100 Hz input and the result. When I zoom in, it is nice I think

Comment: Coupling capacitors C4, C2 have a high reactance at 100 Hz...try larger ones, but you'll have to extend the time scale while they settle to a steady state.

Comment: @OnurTR I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grN8Z.png) with the MC1496 using 1 MHz and 1 kHz. I use appropriately sized caps.

Comment: It looks perfect to me.

Comment: @jonk thanks a lot I appreciate your effort. I understand I have to use bigger caps for smaller impedances. However, I am wondering if polarized caps cause problems when used with AC.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks sir I needed clarification. I understand the problem. I always stay away from using bigger caps as they take up more time to charge/discharge, but they work nicely when it comes to reducing impedances. Am I thinking wrong or are my concerns real sir?

Comment: @OnurTR The larger capacitor is required for the signal that modulates the carrier and that capacitor will likely be biased so that it experiences only one polarity. So a polarized capacitor can be used there, for example. The carrier capacitor can also be polarized (same reason) but usually can be small enough to use a non-polar. (Though in your case with 100 kHz perhaps you'd want a polarized cap there, too.) Do you want me to post up the MC1496 schematic? Or are you fine with your own schematic, for now?

Comment: @jonk Thanks sir , I understand now. So for a polarized capacitor, voltage across the cap must be all positive or all negative with respect to how we place it. This is what I infer sir.

Comment: @jonk I am fine sir with my design thank you a lot

Comment: @OnurTR [Here's the schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKwz3.png), anyway. Just in case.